# How to import an sql file of the northwind database to PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, import, northwind

I am using the most recent version of PostgreSQL, and Pgadmin 4.
And I am attempting to import this database from git: https://github.com/pthom/northwind_psql

I attempted to load the sql file as a restore, and recieved this error:

[image: Error of import to PostgreSQL]

Answer (score 0):

This file is not intended for a pg_restore. You should to just execute it on psql.

> pg_restore is a utility for restoring a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump in one of the non-plain-text formats.

Take a look to `create_db` on GitHub shell script to understand how to import it.

Comment: I did that before but there was no indication that it had actually saved. I'll mention my process for others like me who are new.   1. Select database, 2. Select "Tools" then Query Tool. 3. Select the Open Folder symbol, upload the database desired. 4 Last hit F5, or the lightning symbol to execute this database. At this point it should be loaded. I was expecting a save option but closing, and opening the Query tool again and running this sql statement "SELECT * FROM Customers;" -- now shows that it indeed did save the data as they populate fine below.