# pgAdmin 4 v1.6 restore failed (exit code: 500) mac

Tags: sql, macos, postgresql, pgadmin

I want to practice querying, but I can't restore .sql datasets in pgAdmin 4 on my mac.

I'm new to this so I'm sure someone will be able to help me out. I attached a couple pics to better describe what's going on.

I start by creating the database and going to restore. I select the .sql file I want and click 'Restore'.

Then this error message pops up:[image: Then this error message pops up.]

And when I click through for more details I get this:[image: And when I click through for more details I get this.]

If someone could help me out that'd be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Almost same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701877/how-to-import-an-sql-file-of-the-northwind-database-to-postgresql In few words: you should to execute `.sql` file using query tool, not "restore" it. Also read more about `pg_restore` and `psql` utilities.